# Sklearn: TypeError: Singleton array array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have train dataframe, part of them is

```
date    city    brand   model   price   count
2016-02 abakan  audi    a6  200 тыс - 500 тыс   1
2016-02 abakan  bmw 5-series    200 тыс - 500 тыс   2
2016-02 abakan  bmw x5  200 тыс - 500 тыс   2
2016-02 abakan  chery   a15 200 тыс - 500 тыс   1
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   200 тыс - 500 тыс   3
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   500 тыс - 1 млн 10
2016-02 abakan  chevrolet   lacetti 200 тыс - 500 тыс   1
2016-02 abakan  gaz 69  до 200 тыс  2
2016-02 abakan  honda   element 200 тыс - 500 тыс   1
```

and part of test is

```
date    city    brand   model   price
2016-12 abakan  audi    a6  200 тыс - 500 тыс
2016-12 abakan  bmw 5-series    200 тыс - 500 тыс
2016-12 abakan  bmw x5  200 тыс - 500 тыс
2016-12 abakan  chery   a15 200 тыс - 500 тыс
2016-12 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   200 тыс - 500 тыс
2016-12 abakan  chevrolet   cruze   500 тыс - 1 млн
2016-12 abakan  chevrolet   lacetti 200 тыс - 500 тыс
```

I need to predict `count`
I use code

```
X = pd.read_excel('result_drom2.xlsx')
X_predict = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
y = X.count
del X['count']
label = LabelEncoder()
def cat_to_num(df, column):
    dicts = {}
    label.fit(df[column].drop_duplicates())
    dicts[column] = list(label.classes_)
    df[column] = label.transform(df[column])

cat_to_num(X, 'date')    
cat_to_num(X, 'city')
cat_to_num(X, 'brand')
cat_to_num(X, 'model')
cat_to_num(X, 'price')

cat_to_num(X_predict, 'date') 
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'city')
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'brand')
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'model')
cat_to_num(X_predict, 'price')

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
y_predict = model.predict(X_predict)
y_predict.to_excel('res.xlsx')
```

But this code return an error

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(<bound method DataFrame.count of , dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Where does the error come from ?

Comment: from `model.fit(X, y)` @MMF

Comment: could your print `X.shape` just before `model.fit`?

Comment: @MMF it returns `(24199, 5)`

Comment: and what about `y` ?

Comment: I have found my error, my column has name `count` and there is a function and when I try `y = X.count` it doesn't add a value in this column. Thank you for the help! @MMF